# How to refresh an entity before it is saved, with angular-wakanda API

Tags: angularjs, wakanda

Before we used to have a `serverRefresh()` method to refresh the entity, with the WAF. It triggers the `init` event server side.

I don't see any way to do that now with the angular-wakanda connector.

Am I missing something?

How can I initialize some data for a newly created entity before saving it with the Angular-Wakanda connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version 1.1.0 and higher (from 5/11/16)**

With version 1.1.0 and higher, you have to use `$recompute()` method, that do the same stuff as old (see below) `$serverRefresh()` method.

You can find its documentation on [Angular-Wakanda Entity API Reference](http://wakanda.github.io/angular-wakanda/#/doc/api-reference/entity).

**Version <1.1.0**

On the <del>current</del> version (1.0.4) of Angular-Wakanda, you *still* can do that by calling `$serverRefresh()` on your entity.

```
var entity = ds.Product.$create();
entity.$serverRefresh().$promise.then(function () {
  //Your entity is updated with calculated attributes filled, and right events executed
});
```

What `$serverRefresh()` does is the following:

- On a newly created attribute (not saved yet), it will trigger `init` then `clientrefresh` events server-side, then update the client-side entity
- On an already saved entity, it will trigger `clientrefresh` event server-side, then update client-side entity

Indeed, it's deprecated and will be removed. But, it will be replaced on 1.1.0 version by another, well-documented and non-ambiguous, method that will have the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I will test that and give feedback. That sounds great. Is the repo for the new version private?

Comment: @Ganbin Yes it's private for now, it will be published soon.

Answer (score 1):

From now on $serverRefresh() is a deprecated feature and will be definitely removed in the next 1.1.0 release from the Angular-Wakanda connector.
You could use $fetch() method on your entity, it will fetch it again and update all its attributes. Then apply your modifications and call $save().
For a new Created entity, you can proceed as following :

```
            var newProduct = ds.Product.$create();
            newProduct.productName = "myProductName";
            newProduct.price = 5.5;
            newProduct.$save();
```

And this $save() trigger the event init().

Comment: The $create method doesn't trigger the init event.

Comment: It does, i just tested it, Are you sure you are making the init event public ?
if you did , add a Breakpoint and see if the debugger run .

Comment: This is strange. On my side the $create method doesn't trigger the init method. I have made it public(even if I never had to set the scope of an event server side, it sound odd for me) the $create method don't do anycall to the server so how can it trigger anything? Are you sure you are not savingvthe entity? Cause the save will trigger the init even. But in my case I want to initialize some fileds before to save.

Comment: Yes you are right it's the $save method that trigger the init event and no need to make the scope public, but what i understood is :
If the entity is the first time saved it will trigger the init event then the save event.
If the entity is loaded and already exists , it will trigger only the save event.
What are exactly your needs ? when $save() trigger the init event you can initialize you fields, then the save event will be called.

Comment: I want to initialize some datas that will be render in the client side BEFORE I can save anything. For example, I have somebody from company X logged in my app. I want that when he create a new task, that the company field is already filled by the company of my current logged user. But it doesn't really matter what kind of business logic is behind. The WAF use to give this ability. So I wish to find a way to trigger this init event before to save. I should be able to do server side calculation before to allow the user to enter data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$fetch()](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Angular-Wakanda/Entity/fetch.301-1072167.en.html) method on your entity, it will fetch it and update all its attributes, Then apply your modifications and call $save().

Refer also to : 
[angular-wakanda doc](http://wakanda.github.io/angular-wakanda/#/doc/api-reference/entity)

Comment: The $fetch method doesn't trigger the init event.

Comment: The init event is triggered just after a new entity is created in memory on the server. 

You can use this event to initialize attribute values, 
To associate an init event to the "lastName" attribute:

model.Employee.lastName.events.init = function(event){
    this.lastName = " ";
}

When you  create a new entity using $create the init event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks I know all that. I just can't achieve to trigger this init event with the angular connector. Im using Wakanda before the V1 exist (2012). Im totally aware of the Wakanda workflow. The $fetch method cannot be applied for a new entity that is not yet created and store on the database.

Comment: When I try the $fetch on an newEntity that is not saved, I get an error : $fetch error - no key nor pointer was found.

Comment: I even try to do that way : Get an entity with firstName, lastName and fullName(calculated), modify the firstName, $fetch(), in the result, the fullName was not updated with the new firstName I just modify but with the firstName that was store before on the server. so the new calculation is not working until I do the save. I don't know if this is right or not because maybe some calculation will broke if we didn't pass the validation rules for a new entity so maybe it is a normal behavior. But it should calculate the fullName with the new firstName even before the save() method is called, no?

Comment: You are right, Neither  $create() nor $fetch()  trigger the init event, it triggered only when calling $save(). as i see, right now there is no method that do the same as serverRefresh() in angular-wakanda connector